# Windows Server - IP Alias

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012, hosts-file

I currently have a Windows server that runs iis, SQL and SSIS packages.

All of the programs above have connection string configs using the servers local IP address.

However, we are about to move our hosting provider therefore the IP address will change.

What I would like to know is...

Is there a way that I can give the local IP a friendly name e.g. 'Web-server' and then update all connection strings to use this friendly name instead of IP, that way when I move host I just assign the friendly name to the new IP?

Comment: That's exactly what DNS is.

Comment: Friendly as in why not just switch to using the machine name? Not always available, but sounds like a possibility.

Comment: @Patrick yes something like that is what I'm after

Comment: @SLaks not sure what you mean by that, can you expand?

Comment: As @SLaks said, this is DNS, and is exactly what you are after. Just change the IP over to the machine name in the connection strings and test to verify everything works.

Comment: DNS maps domain names to IP addresses.  You should set up a DNS server.

Comment: @Patrick yes but I am going to be moving to a new host and to a new physical machine, do I not need to create a alias and register it somehow in the server?

Comment: @Patrick  if I were to change everything to use machine name, when I move host would I just need to make sure the machine name was the same?

Comment: In theory, yes, that would do it. You'll want to talk to your host beforehand to see if they would even let you control that though as many don't. Setting up additional DNS as suggested by @SLaks is a much better solution, but the details of that are outside my wheelhouse.

Comment: @Patrick I will have full root access to the new server so imagine I will be able to change the name

Comment: @SLaks when you say setup additional dns, do you mean in the local hosts file?

Comment: No; I mean run your own DNS server and configure it with your servers.